# Xubuntu 16.04 - Thunar doesn't show most of media thumbnails

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, xfce, thunar, thumbnails

Thunar (1.6.10-2ubuntu1) only shows images edited with gimp.

Even the screenshots have no thumbnails.

[image]

I have installed *tumbler* and *tumbler-plugins-extra* packages.

I have reistalled *thunar*. I have already run:

```
    mv ~/.config/Thunar ~/.config/Thunar.bak
```

**How to fix the thumbnails?**

P.S: I have also installed nautilus, and shows all the thumbnails.

Comment: ANSWER FOUND: sudo chmod 701 -R .cache/thumbnails

Comment: Then please add that as an answer.

Comment: @GeoMint yes, please post as an answer. Also, are you sure you need `701`? `700` would make more sense or, at least `710` but not `701`.

Comment: i tested it by changing numbers. everything works for 70x where x is a number different than 0. also 777 works. i will be more specific at my answer. @terdon

Comment: Yes, `777` will work. All you really need is the 1st 7. The rest shouldn't be relevant and there is no reason to give everyone execute access and no read access to the directory, which is what the final `1` in `701` does. You probably just want `755` (rwx for you, rx for everyone else)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make the cache available to programs, by running:

```
sudo chmod 755 -R .cache/thumbnails
```

This also works for more programs like *Image Viewer* that uses the same cache file.

Comment: That'll work for the current directory; what about all directories?

Comment: No, param -R means "Recursive" so it will traverse thru all directories. Working like a charm - thanks!

Comment: I also had to kill Thunar and tumblerd. After changing access permissions, opened Thunar and everything was working.